# Remove layer file from MXDs with multiple data frames using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, data-frame, layer-file

I have a bunch of mxd's and I want to remove layer file from them. Each mxd has 2 and more data frame. I don't know why it does not remove.

I'm trying this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxd
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxd)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[0]    
    df2 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[1] 
    Layer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\GIS\practical_shapefile\residence\residence.lyr")
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, Layer1)
    print 'remove'
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df2, Layer1)
    print 'remove'
    mapdoc.save()
del mxd
```

This prints out:

```
Project.mxd 
remove 
remove 
Project2.mxd 
remove 
remove 
Project3.mxd 
remove 
remove
```

Comment: Where do you import arcpy? What messages do you see when you run that precise code?  Also, you are creating a new layer object from a *.lyr file, when I would have expected that you would have looked for the layer by name using ListLayers, or perhaps by its data source if the name was variable and you wanted any layers with that data source removed.

Comment: i get a message: Project.mxd
                 remove
                 remove
                 Project2.mxd
                 remove
                 remove
                 Project3.mxd
                 remove
                 remove

Comment: It seems that py actuate the code, but when I open the mxd's it don't change

Comment: I would not expect your code as it stands to modify your maps.  What is the name of the layer that you want to remove from every data frame of every map in your folder?

Comment: the name is residence.lyr

Comment: That looks like the name of a layer file that you have saved from a layer rather than a layer name.  Can you confirm that there are layers in your Table of Contents called "residence.lyr"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

and this code remove layer file from MXDs by layer name in the table of content:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis"   
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname 
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"F:\Projects\Guy\mikta3\gis\\" + mxdname)
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if lyr.name == "residence":
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                print 'remove'


    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: Technically this is removing a layer not a layer file. To remove a layer file from a map (*.mxd) does not make much sense because a layer file is a separate *.lyr file.

Answer (score 3):

This code is based on the example code in the [RemoveLayer documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000039000000) and I've just modified it to look more like your variable and layer names:

```
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc, "", df):
        if lyr.name.lower() == "residence":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```

Using the above should work without much change to fit in with your code.

However, your "equivalent" code is currently:

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[0]    
df2 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[1] 
Layer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\GIS\practical_shapefile\residence\residence.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, Layer1)
print 'remove'
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df2, Layer1)
```

In your code the problems I see are:

1. Where you set `df` and `df2` you are looking for the first and second data frames called "Layers" in each map.  I am pretty sure that your data frames will have different names.
2. You've created a layer object called `Layer1` from `residence.lyr` but you have not added this to your map so it cannot be removed, or used to remove something else.
3. To get hold of layers to be deleted you will be better iterating through ListLayers to locate layers with your target name - as in the example code at the top.

Answer (score 0):

this code remove layer file from MXDs by data source:

```
import arcpy,os,sys
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = r"C:\Project"   
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname 
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
    dfList = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")
    for df in dfList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if lyr.dataSource == r"C:\Project\layers\New File Geodatabase.gdb\ways":
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                print 'remove'

    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: Technically this is removing a layer not a layer file.  To remove a layer file from a map (*.mxd) does not make much sense because a layer file is a separate *.lyr file.

Comment: if you change the GDB with layer file it works

Comment: There is no layer file mentioned in your code.  Your code is working with layers (layer objects), not layer files.